# Open my php page as PDF

Tags: php, pdf, file-io

I have a button on my page that links to the report.php page. What I want is that instead of clicking the button and see the php page, to click the button and open this report.php page as a PDF one.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: And the content is PDF? or you want it magically to transform to pdf?

Comment: the contect is html, and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate PDF and allow user to download it (if browser supports inline PDF display it will look as you want). Try [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php). It generates PDFs from HTML and CSS.

Comment: In case I have PHP code inside the html this this is not working? Is there a way to get my php file as a static one and then convert it to pdf?

Comment: You can use [ob_start](http://ua2.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean](http://ua2.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) functions and simply `include` your file in between. It will give you the final HTML which you can then pass to mPDF.

Comment: But I suppose I have to rearrange my page so as to fit in a A4 page for the pdf?

Comment: My problem now is that all the styles I have for spans are not working. Also z-index, position:absolute and negative values like margin-left:-10px, are not working either. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to reformat your HTML. mPDF doesn't support everything, so it needs to be adopted to render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc its possible,  you define headers and make a recommended file name istead of the extension php

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

first example found on php.net

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

assuming of course that the file your generating is compatible with pdf, you can find alot of pdf generators online but i would recommend using http://phpclasses.org

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/), HTML to PDF Converter. Convert your HTML to PDF and then display on screen, Here are [examples](http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php).

Comment: Ok I tried this one. Should my php file has a specific format? Cause I am getting some Fatal Error:  Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'Requested HTML document contains no data.' in /var/www/magmito/dompdf/include/frame_tree.cls.php:114

Comment: Your PHP file should output HTML.

Comment: I suppose it does, although it contains css and PHP code too. Is this a problem?